# C++ std::map failing on "*"?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, stdmap

I was writing a sample c++ program to experiment with polymorphism and maps.
I have the following map:

```
map<char,Operation*> ops;
ops['+'] = new Addition();
ops['-'] = new Subtraction();
ops['*'] = new Multiplication();
ops['/'] = new Division();
```

each class inherits from `Operation` and does the operation suggested by its name.

Everytrhing works fine, but when I access to `ops['*']` the program crashes. If I use a different `char`, say this:

```
ops['x'] = new Multiplication();
```

the program works.

The whole `main` function is this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    char op = argv[2][0];
    int y = atoi(argv[3]);
    map<char,Operation*> ops;
    ops['+'] = new Addition();
    ops['-'] = new Subtraction();
    ops['*'] = new Multiplication();
    ops['/'] = new Division();
    cout<<ops[op]->op(x,y)<<endl;
}
```

I will repeat my problem:

If I pass `1 * 1` to the main, a crash occurs (`SegmentationFault`).
If I edit the code and pass `1 x 1` it works fine.

Is there something I'm missing of `std::map`? Maybe something related to `*` being used as a wildcard or something?

Comment: Look up the term "memory leak" and then never use `new` again.

Comment: `*` is a special character in a lots of shells, which basically expands to all files in the current directory, Try to pass `1 \* 1`.

Comment: @nwp It's not a leak if I clean this up when I should. Here I don't because it's a toy program and everything dies right away!

Comment: @Holt I didn't think about the command line behaviour! It now works. Write that as an answer and I'll give you well deserved points!

Comment: You need to use backslash `\*`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your C++ code — even if it cool be improved by using [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointers — but rather the way you pass arguments to your program when you run it.

The `*` character has a special meaning in a lots of shell, and typically expand to the list of files in the current directory, e.g.:

```
$ ls
main.cpp main
$ echo 1 * 1
1 main.cpp main 1
```

You need to either escape it with a backslash `\` or pass it within quotes when calling your program:

```
$ echo 1 \* 1
1 * 1
$ echo 1 "*" 1
```

I would recommend using the backslash version because some shell may expand  `*` even within standard quotes.

In your case, if your program is called `main`, you would do:

```
$ ./main 1 \* 1 ex
```

Comment: My focus was on the map right now, I will surely look into `unique_ptr`! Thank you!